# Bound absolute value of maximum with function of norms

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

Consider the following operation

\begin{align*}
a=\left|\underset{1\leq j\leq n}{\max}\frac{1}{n-j+1}\left(\sum_{i=j}^{n}r_{i}\right)^{2}-\underset{1\leq j\leq n}{\max}\frac{1}{n-j+1}\left(\sum_{i=j}^{n}s_{i}\right)^{2}\right|,
\end{align*}
where $n$ , $r_{i}$ and $s_{i}$ are given scalars. Is it possible
to bound $a$ by a function of the following norms $|r-s|_1,  |r-s|_2, |r-s|_\infty$
please? By definition, we have

\begin{align*}
|r-s|_{1}= & \sum_{i=1}^{n}|r_{i}-s_{i}|,\\
|r-s|_{2}= & \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n}|r_{i}-s_{i}|^{2}},\\
|r-s|_{\infty}= & \underset{1\leq j\leq n}{\max}|r_{i}-s_{i}|.
\end{align*}
 Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but my bet is that it cannot be true in the general case, as I cannot even make it work for $n=1$. Namely, in this case, $a=\left|r_1^2-s_1^2\right|$, which is not a function of $|r_1-s_1|$. Note in this case all three norms coincide with $|r_1-s_1|$ so it is not a function of those norms either.

Comment: Thank you @StinkingBishop. In fact, instead of expressing it as a function of norms, I aim to bound it by a function of norms. I have rewritten the question following your comment, thanks.